# Can VBScript do what I want?

Tags: vbscript, batch-file

Having never used VBScript before, I just want to make sure I'm headed down the right path before I launch into it.

I need to create a process that will run via Windows Scheduler on a weekly basis.

I need the script to do the following:

1. Call PSFTP.exe and open a SSH session to a SFTP site, download a file and save it in a particular folder.
2. Unzip the files after download.
3. Open Truecrypt and mount encrypted volumes.
4. Activate a few other processes via the cmd line, in order.

All of this needs to be in order and each step needs to wait for the previous step to finish.

Can I achieve this using VBScript or a combination of VBScript and BAT files?  Or should I be going down a different route?

Thanks in advance!

GPC

Comment: Yes you can do that.  The unzip part you will need another program to do so check out 7zip.

Comment: Not familiar with trueCrypt so not sure if they have a command line option but you can send key strokes and that may accomplish what you need in a very kludgy way... but it is possible

Comment: if you are not familiar with VBS why do you want to use it at all? you might just put all your commands in a BAT file and schedule with AT.

Answer (score 1):

in its simplest form, what you want may be achieved with this short BAT file

```
::: C:\DEST\SO.BAT :::
pushd c:\dest
echo cd downloads > psftp.scr
echo get file.zip >> psftp.scr
echo quit >> psftp.scr
psftp user@domain.com -pw password -b psftp.scr
7z x -o file.zip
truecrypt /q /v myvolume
```

and schedule it to run every monday with this command

```
AT 09:00 /EVERY:MONDAY C:\DEST\SO.BAT
```

or (thanks, iesou!) in case you need specific user rights, want a task specific name... with

```
schtasks /create /SC Weekly /MO 1 /D Friday /TN "File Download and Extract" /TR "C:\DEST\SO.BAT" /ST 09:00 /RU PCNAME\USER /RP PASSWORD
```

Comment: You can also use the schtasks command `schtasks /create /SC Weekly /MO 1 /D Friday /TN "File Download and Extract" /TR "C:\DEST\SO.BAT" /ST 09:00 /RU PCNAME\USER /RP PASSWORD` I would recommend it in case you need specific user rights, want a task specific name etc.